# Angularjs: Promise doesn't update Binding

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I'm using a promise. But when my promise resolves the binding to the view doesn't bind to the new value.

I made a small jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/58q8khap/8/

Here's the view:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!
</div>
```

and the code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope,ownservice) {
    $scope.name = "Noname";
    ownservice.getname().then(function(result){
        $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    });
}

myApp.service('ownservice', function ($q) {
    this.getname = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        setTimeout(function() {
                deferred.resolve('Superhero');
        } , 1000);
        return deferred.promise;
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the use of `setTimeout` by the angular version `$timeout`. That way angular will force a digest cycle and refresh your scope

Working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/cunuj46w/

Note that you should really use angular-powered versions of globals like $timeout or $window also for testing/mocking purposes

Comment: Ah my problem is another one. And this was a simple sample. But due your answer I discovered that. Thanks

Comment: It's ok. I think it was a typo or something like that

Answer (score 1):

after this line

```
 $scope.name = 'Superhero';
```

add

```
$scope.$apply();
```